# How To Write Data In File Using Php By Incrementing By Id

Tags: php

When a user opens the page there is a count variable which increments by one. The count variable as well as the data are written in a file.

The problem concerns the session variable which is not incrementing. Every time the page loads there should be a increment in the session which should be put into the file.

```
<?php
session_start();
$count=1;
if(!isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $txt = "abc.txt"; 
    $_SESSION["hello"] = $count++;
    if (isset($_POST['field1']) && isset($_POST['field2'])) { 
        $_SESSION["favanimal"] = "cat";
        $fh = fopen($txt, 'a'); 
        $txt=$a . '-' .$_POST['field1'].' - '.$_POST['field2']; 

        fwrite($fh,$txt); // Write information to the file
        fclose($fh); // Close the file

    }
    echo $_SESSION["hello"];
}

?>
```

HTML code is:

```
<form action="index.php" method="POST">
    <input name="field1" type="text" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Save Data">
</form>
```

Comment: Where is `$a` defined?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are storing the *hello* session variable, but not reading from it. So indeed, you set it to 1 each time.

Change this:

```
$_SESSION["hello"] = $count++;
```

to:

```
// read count from the session variable, if it exists, or else
// start with 0
$count = isset($_SESSION["hello"]) ? $_SESSION["hello"] : 0;
// increment that counter and store it back into the session variable:
$_SESSION["hello"] = $count + 1;
```

Note that currently you are not writing this value to the file, but just echo it. I suppose that you know what to do with that. It could be a line like this (before the file is closed):

```
    fwrite($fh, "Number of visits during session: " . $_SESSION['hello']);
```

NB: *$a* is not defined in the piece of code you provided. Make sure it has a value before using it in an expression.

Comment: I have elaborated the problem sorry my English is not so good in the question.

Comment: It is a pitty, because you ***changed*** the question. First it was a problem with the counter, which you have fixed, and now you mention a different problem concerning appending. That should have been a new question. It is not respectful that you ignore the answers for the counter problem, but just correct it in your question. You should accept an answer for the counter problem, and then ask a new question.

Comment: ok i am accepting your answer but for my poor english i was unable to elaborate what i was trying to say

Comment: Your English is good enough, no problem there. But you know that you corrected the code for the session counter. Please, put also back your question as before and ask the appending issue as a new question. I will be happy to help you with the answer. Just tell me in comments when you have posted it and I will have a look.

Comment: i have posted the new question kindly check it

Answer (score 0):

You don't need $count variable. If it stays like this, then $count will become 1 every time the page is loaded. I think this is what you want:

```
<?php
session_start();
//$count=1;

//change session variable here!!!
if(isset($_SESSION["hello"]))
    $_SESSION["hello"]++;
else 
    $_SESSION["hello"] = 1;

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){//you don't need ! here
    $txt = "abc.txt"; 
    if (isset($_POST['field1']) && isset($_POST['field2'])) { 
    $_SESSION["favanimal"] = "cat";
    $fh = fopen($txt, 'a'); 

    $txt=$_POST['field1'].' - '.$_POST['field2']; 

    fwrite($fh,$txt); // Write information to the file
    fclose($fh); // Close the file

    }
}

echo $_SESSION["hello"];

?>

<form action="index.php" method="POST">
    <input name="field1" type="text" />
    <input name="field2" type="text" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Save Data">
</form>
```